# Creating a signature in HTML - Office 365 - dynamic URL Link

Tags: html, office365

By not working I mean the hyper link behind [www.CompanyURL.com](http://www.CompanyURL.com) is not working. You cannot Click or Ctrl+Click on [www.CompanyURL.com](http://www.CompanyURL.com).

I am trying to create a company wide signature to use it for Office 365. Most of the data is pulled from the Office 365 account, personal details.

Our group has 3 companies and for each company there is an unique URL link. We decided to put the URL link in the Department field.

The below is working fine, while **not** using the URL link stored in the Department field. The goal is to replace the hardcoded URL link with the data stored in field/variable %%Department%%

```
<span><a href="https://www.CompanyURL.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="font-size: 9pt;color: #0000cd;text-decoration:none !important"><span style="text-decoration: none !important;">&nbsp;www.CompanyURL.com</span></a></span>
```

Below is how I can write the data using data stored in the field/variable %%Department%%.

```
<span><strong>%%Department%%</strong></span>
```

It will print `www.CompanyURL.com`.

How can I use the URL link stored in the `%%Department%%` field? I tried the below and the link is not Clickable.

```
<span><a v-bind:href="%%Department%%" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span style="text-decoration: none !important;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;%%Department%%</span></a></span>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. "Doesn't work" isn't specific. What's the actual problem? What is `:href`? Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Is this some sort of Outlook 365 template language?

Comment: Microsoft allows you to put some HTML code to have a company wide disclaimer. As a workaround it can be used as a signature as well.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `v-bind:` before the `href=`? That looks like [VueJS](https://vuejs.org) and I don't think you're using that, so I'm guessing that's your problem

Comment: I added more details to the description.
:href is alias for v-bind:href

Comment: yeah in VueJS but I don't think you should be using a vue binding. probably just `<a href="%%Department%%">` is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Thank You!
I made it work. It seems adding https:// and removing v-bind did the trick.

```
<span>
<a href="mailto:%%Email%%" style="font-size:10pt; color:#0000cd; text-decoration:none">
<span>%%Email%%</span></a>
<span>
<a href="https://%%Department%%" target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="font-size: 10pt;color:#0000cd;text-decoration:none">
<span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;%%Department%%</span>
</a>
</span>
```